# UIRefreshControl does not work

Tags: ios, swift, pull-to-refresh, uirefreshcontrol

My project is still using Swift 2.3 and is not migrated to Swift 3 yet. When I pull down table view with the following code I can verify that refreshed data can be seen in Debug Area, but it doesn't reflect on the table view.  I tried it both on IOS 9 and IOS 10.

```
 var refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

 if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    TableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
 } else {
    TableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
 }

 refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.handleRefresh), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

 func handleRefresh(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
     refreshControl.beginRefreshing()

     Search()
     TableView.reloadData()

     refreshControl.endRefreshing()
 }
```

Comment: Is your search() function async?   If so the `reloadData()` method may be running prior to search() completing.  If it's async try moving the `reloadData()` and `endRefreshing` calls into search() and ensure they run once search actually finishes running..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `tableView.reloadData()` to a place where you can be sure the `search()` function has completed and returned results.  If that is an async function then add a completion handler so that you know when to call `reloadData()`. Then you could call the function like so:

```
search {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Or, when you're on Swift 3

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try reloading the tableView on the main thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```